# Unable to get LocalVariableInfo from MethodBody using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I have a requirement to retrieve local variables information(variable name and 
its values) within a method.I tried using reflection.But "**body.LocalVariables**" is returning null. PFB Code.

```
  var type = result.CompiledAssembly.GetType("SUITTestRunner.FooClass");
  var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Execute");
  methodInfo.Invoke(obj, null);
  MethodBody body = methodInfo.GetMethodBody();
  foreach (LocalVariableInfo info in body.LocalVariables)
  {
      //Some Code..
  }
```

PFB code for Execute() method:

```
public void Execute()
{ 
   int d;
  int c=1;
}
```

Please correct me if i'm wrong,I was assuming **"body.LocalVariables"** will hold d and c fields information present in Execute().

Comment: Because `Execute` method you never uses `c` or `d`, these local variables were probably optimized away by compiler (especially in Release mode)

Comment: I have tried after using them.Thought it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

We will be able to fetch full  method information using Semantic Analysis.I was able to fetch variable information(including variables names and their values) using "root" method. PFB link for implementation.
**https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Semantic-Analysis**